# Is there difference between using successor and predecessor in RBT?

Tags: data-structures, red-black-tree

Hey I'm a junior student major in computer science, I want to ask is the final tree will be the same when you are using successor or predecessor when deleting in red-black tree? Thanks.

Comment: There are several variants of Red-Black trees. Some are 2-3 trees, others are 2-3-4 trees. They may be left-leaning or right-leaning as well or have no leaning.
I'm not sure what you mean by predecessor or successor.

Comment: @AminM so in the uni, my lecture taught me that when delete a node in RBT, you can either replace it with predecessor (the highest value node in the left subtree) or successor (the lowest value node in the right subtree). But Im not sure about the leaning though

Comment: Leaning is a way to make RBTs much simpler.. look it up
I'd suspect that they'd be different but I don't have the data to back it up.. delete can be complex. I alway thought of RBTs as growing by popping the middle item up.. and shrinking by sucking the parent in.

Comment: You'll end up with different trees depending on whether you choose to swap with the successor or predecessor.  Either one will be valid, though.

Comment: @MattTimmermans alright thanks for the answer.. appreciate it